# NoClassDefFoundError -> How can I make this kotlin code work to implement a MQTT connection?

Tags: android, kotlin, mqtt, noclassdeffounderror

I found this code on [this](https://www.emqx.io/blog/android-connects-mqtt-using-kotlin) site, it implements an MQTT client for Android, and it's written in Kotlin.

I have really few experience with this language, so I don't understand how to make it work. I copied it into my MainActivity.kt file and I'm calling connect(this) from onCreate function:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        connect(this)
        ...
```

This is the connect function:

```
    private fun connect(context: Context){


        var serverURI = "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883"
        mqttClient = MqttAndroidClient(context, serverURI, "SmartFarmerApp")
        mqttClient.setCallback(object: MqttCallback{
            override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Receive message: ${message.toString()} from topic: $topic")
            }

            override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost ${cause.toString()}")
            }

            override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })

        val options = MqttConnectOptions()
        try {
            mqttClient.connect(options, null , object: IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection success")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failure")
                }
            })
        }catch( e: MqttException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

The first line inside the try block gives me an error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager;

What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding a line into build.gradle (module). I added this one:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:30.x.x'
```

that number 30 is my compileSdkVersion, that I found in the same file

Answer (score 1):

When running within an `Activity`, you can provide `this` as the `Context` (as `Activity` is a `Context` class). When running elsewhere, you'd need to see where to obtain the `Context` from, which is eg. `this.getContext()` within a `Fragment` (assuming the `Fragment` is attached to an `Activity`). In this case, even the (non-themed) `ApplicationContext` should suffice.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Maybe I have a different problem then. I'm invoking connect(this) inside onCreate function. Inside the connect function I have a "NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager". The line that throws the error is the first line inside the try block , exactly when I call mqttClient.connect(options, null, object: IMqttActionListener)